# pointer segfault vs undefined behavior

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, buffer-overflow

Why does this code produce a segfault when running regularly, but undefined behavior instead of a segfault if I either add a command line argument or comment out calling the `cpy` function?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int *p;

void fn() {
    int n[1];
    n[0]=99;
    p = n;

}

void cpy(char *v) {
    char x[8];
    strncpy(x,v,8);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fn();
    cpy(argv[1]);
    cout << "p[0]:" << p[0];
}
```

I know `n` is a local var for the function `fn`, but is there a way I can overflow a buffer or enter something as `argv[1]` to get it to print the value that `n` held from wherever it is/was in memory?

Comment: Undefined behavior? If you add a command line argument, it is stored in argv[1]. If you comment out the cpy() line, you aren't using argv[1] anywhere, and that's what is causing the segfault.

Comment: But why does not using `argv[1]` cause a segfault? I meant undefined behavior printing the index of `p` which is pointing to an out of scope variable.

Comment: Wait, as in not providing a cmdline arg, or not using the variable argv[1]?

Comment: Well yeah, why does adding a command line arg make it so that trying to print a null pointer no longer causes a segfault? I can't tell how `argv` has any effect on printing the pointer.

Comment: It doesn't. The segfault occurs before trying to print out the pointer, when trying to access argv[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass an argument, then `argv[1]==nullptr`. Then `cpy(argv[1])` is `cpy(nullptr)` and cpy invokes `strncpy(x,nullptr,8)` and segfaults.

If you comment out the cpy, then no segfault.

If you pass an argument, then cpy won't segfault. But then you get to a different problem: fn did `p=n` but n was declared on the stack, and so back in main at `cout<<p[0]`, p points at the object n which no longer exists, and so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks that explains 95% of my confusion. Happen to know a way to manipulate the input to get it to print out the data from where `num` was if it wasn't overwritten?

Comment: When you say `num` do you mean the `n[]` declared in fn? You'd need to print it before fn returns, or save it somewhere else before fn returns.

Comment: yeah sorry `n[]` I'm basically trying to get main to print out `99` without changing the code.

Comment: You'd need to do that before calling cpy() (assuming you still are), since it will be overwritten in that function. By commenting out the call to cpy, or moving it below your cout statement, 99 will be printed out.

Comment: In regard to my previous comment, 99 'should' be printed out, but this is undefined behavior, so no guarantees.

Comment: Without changing the code? Try passing a single argument, the empty string. For example: gcc foo.c && ./a.out ""

Comment: That doesn't work. But this seems to: `g++ -O3 foo.cpp && ./a.out c` (the letter c's ascii value is 99)

Comment: @MichaelCook well yes, but is that really the desired behaviour? Its retrieving whatever was in the cmdline arg, which has nothing to do with the data in n[0]. Also the empty string technique wouldn't work, since an empty string is still null terminated, so will have the character '\0', with ascii value 0.

Comment: Well, the challenge was to get the code to print 99 without changing it. I think the point of this homework assignment was to see if the student understands how the stack works.